# SonarQube Leak Period between Branches or Projects

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I am currently introducing SonarQube into a large legacy project. This means that there are already hundreds of warnings, in the first step I would like to ensure that there are **no new warnings** coming from our feature branches.

To achieve this, I want to have the Sonar analysis run on every feature branch, compare it to the main branch and alert the committer in case new warnings have been introduced.

Assume the following situation:

`MyProject 1.0-SNAPSHOT` is the name and version of the project on SonarQube. It has 100 warnings. It represents the `develop` branch. The `leak period` is the analysis from 1 day ago. This works very well, I can see which **new warnings** have been introduced since yesterday.

Developers are working on `feature/somefeature` branches. When they open a pull request, I want a Sonar analysis to run on that branch. This works fine, but I can't set the `leak version` to `MyProject 1.0-SNAPSHOT` from yesterday, because this branch is seen **as a completely separate project** by SonarQube, even though I set the `sonar.projectKey` to the same name and I have also tried playing around with the `sonar.branch` property.

The desired outcome is:

1. develop -> 100 warnings
2. feature/somefeature -> 102 warnings
3. On the SonarQube dashboard of `feature/somefature` display "2 new warnings".

Can it be done with sonar itself, or do I need to write my own program using the Sonar REST API?

Comment: Have you looked here? https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE65/Local+and+Branch+Analysis

Comment: yes, but I didn't find a plugin that matches my requirements

Comment: @enp4yne, have you managed to solve it via Sonar REST API ?

Comment: @StasKolodyuk yes I wrote a little node.js application that does what I need. You can message me for details (I can't share it since it is quite specific to our application)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [Branch Plugin](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Branch+Plugin) in order to analyse branches for only new issues. This plugin has a corresponding Quality Gate:

> For short-lived branches, there is a kind of hard-coded quality gate focusing only on new issues.

**It will create Issues only if there are new bugs or vulnerabilities.**

As per the plugin documentation all your feature branches should be identified as ***short-lived branches***.

**NOTE:** Branch Plugin is licensed under [SonarSource](https://www.sonarsource.com/docs/sonarsource_terms_and_conditions.pdf) and is available in nonfree [Developer Edition](https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/developer/)

Comment: I will accept this answer because it is the correct way to go. However, for anyone else reading this: As far as I can tell you need Sonar Developer or Enterprise Edition, the pricing of which is calculated by the project's lines of code. In a large project, using this 1 plugin will become very expensive very quickly.